# Authenticate Ubuntu users against a macOS Server OpenDirectory LDAP

Tags: login, ldap

My Objective: be able to login via ssh with any network user to Ubuntu 16.04 using the password from LDAP.

The MacOS server "Sierra" has OpenDirectory, Groups and Users configured and I can use LDAP users to login to a couple of services, e.g. gitlab
(gitlab uses encryption: 'plain' and port: 389).

Browsing the LDAP works from Ubuntu:

1. `ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap://192.168.111.1 -b dc=server,dc=example,dc=com 'uid=bob'` shows ldap users entries
2. `ldapsearch` without specifying `-x`, does not work:

   ```
   SASL/CRAM-MD5 authentication started
   Please enter your password
   ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80) additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure
   ```
3. `getent passwd` shows all network users and groups, but if I try to login with a network account:

   ```
   $ su bob
   No passwd entry for user 'bob'
   ```

How can I configure Ubuntu for doing a login with LDAP users?
(The password may be send unencrypted since both Ubuntu and macOS-Server are in VPN)

I have followed [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OSXLDAPClientAuthentication) and tried all kinds of different things.

Comment: I wrote a guide on how to do this recently. This works with Ubuntu although written for Debian. [https://macintosh-rescue.net/index.php/gnu-linux/apple-open-directory-linux-client-setup/](https://macintosh-rescue.net/index.php/gnu-linux/apple-open-directory-linux-client-setup/)